# Make self-bot create a server

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have a discord.js self-bot, and I'm trying to make it create a server, any help would be great.

I've tried messing around with `client.user` but I didn't find anything
Also if you cant create a server using discord.js (because its not meant for selfbots) im willing to use a external library (request, axios etc..)

I'm using [discord.js-selfbot](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord.js-selfbot) (discord.js v12)

```js
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content === '!createserver') {
    // make server here
    message.reply('Created server!')
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

While I don't condone self botting due to terms, but the answer is very easily findable on the documentation for discord.js, right [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/v12/class/GuildManager?scrollTo=create) assuming it exactly copies v12.

The documentation for the endpoint is available [here](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#create-guild) if the copied package does not work. Or just install a working version of it using the *actual* discord.js package, like `npm i discord.js@12.5.3`.

Just be careful with self botting, for obvious reasons.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that it's against TOS, thanks for the answer.